# How to query an encrypted field in SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, encryption

I need to encrypt a field in my sqlite database for android. I am going to use following code to do that. Understand I grap the code from a site. If you have any better idea, please let me know.

```
 public byte[] keyGen() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(192);
    return keyGenerator.generateKey().getEncoded();
 }

 public byte[] encript(byte[] dataToEncrypt, byte[] key)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    //I'm using AES encription
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
    return c.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
  }

  public byte[] decript(byte[] encryptedData, byte[] key)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
    return c.doFinal(encryptedData);
  }
```

Note that the field is long text and has index. Now my question is how to query the encrypted field? I can get a row and decrypt the field from database. But I don't know how to use where clause in this case. Maybe there is a sqlite function to decrypt/encrypt?

UPDATE: I decided to create custom SQLite function to decrypt and encrypt. I think this will resolve the issues in this question.

Comment: You would encrypt the text and use the encrypted byte array with the WHERE clause.

Comment: But that does not work if I include something like "where text='%Babo%'". I think better approach is to create your own Sqlite function for encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: I you have a solution, why not post an answer yourself?